# EF Core ExecuteSqlCommand and parameters

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have to execute an sql command on ef core 1.1.2:

```
 var projectParam = new SqlParameter("@projectid", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = inventory.ProjectId;
 var locationParam = new SqlParameter("@locationid", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = location.Id;
 var scanOrderParam = new SqlParameter("@scanorder", SqlDbType.Int).Value = scanOrder;
 _ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("update Inventories set ScanOrder=ScanOrder+1 where ProjectId = '@projectid' AND LocationId = '@locationid' AND ScanOrder>'@scanorder';",
                  parameters: new[] {
                                     projectParam, locationParam, scanOrderParam
                  });
```

It throws the exception:

- An unhandled exception has occurred: Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.
- If I write ScanOrder>@scanorder into the command it says that scanorder parameter must be declared. Which is an int.
- If I don't use apostrophes at projectid and locationid it throws the exception parameter must be declared.

What is the proper way for using parameters with ef core?

**Edit (solution):**
The problem was the way I declared parameters and give them values. If I use this form it works:

```
var projectParam = new SqlParameter("@projectid", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
projectParam.Value = inventory.ProjectId;
var locationParam = new SqlParameter("@locationid", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
locationParam.Value = location.Id;
var scanOrderParam = new SqlParameter("@scanorder", SqlDbType.Int);
scanOrderParam.Value = scanOrder;
```

Comment: What are the values of `inventory.ProjectId` and `location.Id`?

Comment: @DavidG They are Guid types with values.

Comment: You are not supposed to use single quotes around parameters.

Comment: @Crowcoder Yes, I know that but if I don't use quotes it says: `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Must declare the scalar variable "@projectid".`

Comment: Your question says you removed the quotes from two of the parameters. You must remove them all.  Regardless of other problems, you will never get it working until you first fix that.

Comment: @Crowcoder I tried without any quotes first. This way it says I must declare projectid. If I add quotes to projectid it says I must declare locationid. If I add quotes to locationid it says I must declare scanorder. Which is an int but I I add quotes there too, It starts to complain about the conversion from string to uniqueid.

Comment: What if you don't use EF, just use `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery`? Does it work?

Comment: @Crowcoder I've just tried with ADO.NET and it gave an understandable exception exception right after filling the parameters array: My parameters were just Guid and Int types, not SqlParameter types because of the way I declared them earlier. Now it is working from ef, too. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @DavidG Your question was right at the beginning, I just didn't notice the variables are not sqlparameters just simple types. Thanks!

Comment: The original problem is that the C# '=' operator returns the assigned value.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/assignment-operator  so the variable projectParam was set to inventory.ProjectId, not the new SqlParameter object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var queryItem = new SqlParameter("@table", SqlDbType.Char) {Value = yourValue};
```

Comment: The problem was already solved and I do not see what this answer adds to the solution

Comment: @Klaus It's working and there's no other solution posted to this question (although I wrote down a solution myself). Plus this form is cleaner than the one I have posted, so I accept it.